# Technology for Video Streaming site

Tags: video-streaming

We are evaluating technologies for video streaming site.

I have been a Microsoft guy from last 6 years.

Could anybody here suggest what are the necessary technologies for video streaming sites citing the their characteristics such as:

- scalability,
- performance,
- development effort

Also, some books or other pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: take a look at [wowza streaming server](http://www.wowza.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Since few years lot of technologies has been used for live streaming :

- RTP/RTSP
- RTMP (adobe protocol)
- Smooth streaming (microsoft dynamic streaming)
- HLS (apple dynamic streaming)
- HDS (adobe dynamic streaming)

For professional use, **Wowza Streaming server** is a must since it can adapt your H264 stream for each protocole automaticaly.

**Flash media server** works great too, with the same kind of functionnality but is a little bit more expensive.

**Unified Streaming** works directly as a module for your webserver (apache/nginx). This way of working lower the cost to deploy it and allow you to use some generic HTTP caches/proxies. But this works only with http based protocols (hls,hds, smooth).

**Red5** is great for RTMP/RTP but still don't support any http protocols.